# How can I repeatedly play a sound sample, allowing the next loop to overlap the previous

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, audio

Not sure if this isn't a dupe, but the posts I found so far didn't solve my issue.

---

A while ago, I wrote a (music) [metronome for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/814889/72216). The metronome is written in `python3/Gtk`

To repeatedly play the metronome- tick (a recorded sound sample), I used `subprocess.Popen()` to play the sound, using `ogg123` as a cli tool:

```
subprocess.Popen(["ogg123", soundfile])
```

This works fine, I can easily run up to 240 beats per minute.

#### On WIndows

I decided to rewrite the project on Windows (`python3/tkinter/ttk`). I am having a hard time however to play the sound, repeating the beat sample in higher tempi. The next beat simply won't start while the previous one (appearantly) hasn't finished yet, playing the beat sample.

Is there a way, in `python3` on Windows, I can start playing the next beat while the sample is still playing?

Currently, I am using `winsound`:

```
winsound.Playsound()
```

Running this in a loop has, as mentioned issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) for audio manipulation , including playing repetedly.

Here is an example. You can develop this further using examples from [pydub site.](http://pydub.com/)

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

n = 2

audio = AudioSegment.from_file("sound.wav") #your audio file
play(audio * n)  #Play audio 2 times
```

Change `n` above to the number that you need.

Comment: Thanks! having a bit of trouble setting it up, weird errors, not used to Windows :) will continue tomorrow night. To be continued... Thanks for now!

Comment: Silly question, but are you sure it works on python3? I can't really find any documentation on it.

Comment: I've 2.7 , you may need to follow up documentation on `pydub` site for specific python 3 related installation. I know installation can be a little pain due to dependencies. Once its installed, its smooth though. More details here - `https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub#installation`

Comment: I checked and `pydub` does support `3.x` , so its just matter of getting it working on windows. Good luck

Comment: Not getting it to work on windows unfortunantely. Pretty sure I set the paths correctly and all. How did you install on Liux btw? pip install installs for python2.

Comment: Tried it on python 2.7 (Linux). Unfortunately, it doesn't behave quite well on loops. Unlike ogg123, it seems quite unpredictable how (and mostly: when) the sound is exactly initiated, and it does not overlap, as it turns out. I cannot make it corresponding to a beat-per-minute scale. Thanks a lot though.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want the audio to be greater than fix length like for example 20000 milliseconds or 20s. Then you can simply add the audio repeatedly

```py
sound = AudioSegment.from_file(GENERAL_FOLDER + "/" + "beep.wav", "wav")

sound_extended = sound

while sound_extended < 20000:
    sound_extended = sound_extended + sound
```